# Type 'Observable<void | Observable<void>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Action>'

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I am trying to understand `effects` in `NgRX 6`

I have an example effect:

```
  @Effect()
  createNonce$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(INVALID_SESSION),
    map(() => generateNonce(32)),
    map(nonce => of(this.store.dispatch(new IdentityRedirect(nonce)))),
    catchError(error => of(console.error(error)))
  );
```

What I would like to achieve is

1. Listen for `INVALID_SESSION`
2. Call `generateNonce` and return the result
3. Dispatch the result from the previous map

I am getting the following error though

```
[ts]
Type 'Observable<void | Observable<void>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Action>'.
  Type 'void | Observable<void>' is not assignable to type 'Action'.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Action'.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Effect()
  createNonce$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(INVALID_SESSION),
    mergeMap(() =>
      of(generateNonce(32)).pipe(
        map(nonce => ({ type: REDIRECT_TO_LOGIN, payload: nonce }))
      )
    ),
    catchError(error => of({ type: REDIRECT_TO_LOGIN_FAILURE, payload: error }))
  );
```